# Get Value from DataGrid Cell (WPF)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, datagrid

I am looking for a way to read the value of allways one specific cell 
(Row:0, Column 2) in a DataGrid.

In WinForms it was very easy:

```
var1 = DataGridView1.Item(2, 0).Value
```

I am searching for hours now without finding anything usefull.
It is important that I can choose values programatically, like in the way above, without preselections with mouse etc.

I hope someone knows an answer to that

Regards

Comment: `c#` or `vb.net`?

Comment: vb.net. Please note that this is a WPF project

Comment: if datagrid is data-bound, you should obtain values from from itemSource item. if not data-bound, please provide a complete reproducible example

Comment: I am opening an SQL-Connection an fill the data into a DataGrid. So far so good. 
In row 0 and column 2 is a value I need to assign to a variable. 
And this is the part which I am not able to solve to "just" assign this damn value in Row0 and Column2 to a variable.

So all the data is there in the grid, but i am not able to take it out and use it further

Answer (score 0):

```
        int rowIndex = 2;
        int columnIndex = 0;
        var x = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value;
```

Comment: This is a solution for "WinForms". WPF is the issue I have

Answer (score 0):

i think this code can solve your problem.

```
string  Get_Cell_Value (int column, int row)
    {
        //Get Cell data to TextBlock
        TextBlock cell_data = dgGetInfo.Columns[column].GetCellContent(dgGetInfo.Items[row]) as TextBlock;
        return cell_data .Text.ToString();
    }
```

In the main program you can use it same:

```
cell_data_get = Get_Cell_Value(0,0)
```

It will get data from `column[0], row[0]` in your `DataGrid`
I hope this code can help you.